# Issues passing data from TableViewCell labels to a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to pass data from the selected cell of an "Events" table view, to a "Details" View Controller. I have looked at various questions similar to mine, but I can't seem to properly apply it to my code. I also used labels, instead of a Subtitle style. There is also an image that needs to be passed.

my view controller looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var names = ["Brown Diner", "Kirkland", "Choco", "Lil Wayne", "Annie", "Social"]
    var details = ["Free drink with meal after 12 AM", "LADIES drink free", "10% off all ice cream!", "concert", "a Theater Production", "Bring your Squad to the Social"]
    var images = [UIImage(named: "brown"), UIImage(named: "kirk"), UIImage(named: "choco"), UIImage(named: "lilwayne"), UIImage(named: "default"), UIImage(named: "default")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.detail.text = details[indexPath.row]
        cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
            guard let eventVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController,
                let eventIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
                    return
            }
            eventVC.eventName = names[eventIndex]
            eventVC.eventDetail = details[eventIndex]
            eventVC.eventPhoto = images[eventIndex]
        }
    } 
}
```

my customCell.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var photo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detail: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

my detailsViewController

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var detailsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detailsImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var detailsDesc: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }
}
```

I am very new to Swift, and it has proven to be very challenging for me. I'm really not a coder, however a project demands that I complete some of the coding for an application that I am the UI/UIX designer of. Thank you for your help in advance!

EDIT::
Project: https://github.com/vpags1/events.git.

When the user clicks on a cell in the TableView, it takes you to the Details View which displays the same data as the cell (image, name, details) just larger; and longer descriptions can be see at full length. I am pulling several errors in my View Controller, and thats pretty much all I know.. My cells formatting is also kind of messed up but I was going to try and figure that out after this unless there is a quick fix for that. cheers.

Comment: It looks like everything should be working. Can you specify the problem a bit more? Btw. if you expect the values from the tableView to be present in the `DetailsViewController.viewDidLoad` it will not work because this method gets called **before** `prepareForSegue`. But you will see them in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Are you trying to pass data once the user taps on a tableViewCell?

Comment: put your project on github and provide a link

Comment: First off, for anyone who is trying to help me, I am forever grateful.
I uploaded my project to github, alas. I posted an edit to explain further.  <https://github.com/vpags1/events.git>.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your prepareForSegue function is being called when you tap on the cell.  If not, you can add a didSelectRow function.  Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailsSegue", sender: self)

    }
```

Then when you select your cell it will call your prepareForSegue function.